# Writing image metadata in Java, preferably PNG

Tags: java, image, metadata

I would like to write metadata to a PNG image that I create.

My understanding of Java Advanced Image API is that I should use `IIOMetadata`, but code snippets I found seem overly complicated. Then I searched for a library and found [Sanselan](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/sanselan/Sanselan.html) but it seems a bit old, and not very handy for *writing* metadata.

To actually create the image, I use

```
ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
```

I understand image metadatas are complex to handle due to its XML-like structure. Could anybody point me to a tutorial, solution, or library that will help?

Comment: How did you end up getting this to work? Can you share your code, or answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714345/unable-to-read-write-image-metadata-in-java

Comment: Using [this](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe) library, it is as easy as PNGTweaker.insertTextChunk(ChunkType.TEXT, "keyword", "value", is, os)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I had to do the the same thing some days ago.. I have not found the exact solution on the internet either but looking at the `com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGMetadata` class I could achieve some results..

To write a custom metadata to a PNG file:

```
public byte[] writeCustomData(BufferedImage buffImg, String key, String value) throws Exception {
    ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("png").next();

    ImageWriteParam writeParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    ImageTypeSpecifier typeSpecifier = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    //adding metadata
    IIOMetadata metadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(typeSpecifier, writeParam);

    IIOMetadataNode textEntry = new IIOMetadataNode("tEXtEntry");
    textEntry.setAttribute("keyword", key);
    textEntry.setAttribute("value", value);

    IIOMetadataNode text = new IIOMetadataNode("tEXt");
    text.appendChild(textEntry);

    IIOMetadataNode root = new IIOMetadataNode("javax_imageio_png_1.0");
    root.appendChild(text);

    metadata.mergeTree("javax_imageio_png_1.0", root);

    //writing the data
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageOutputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(baos);
    writer.setOutput(stream);
    writer.write(metadata, new IIOImage(buffImg, null, metadata), writeParam);
    stream.close();

    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Then, to read the data:

```
public String readCustomData(byte[] imageData, String key) throws IOException{
    ImageReader imageReader = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("png").next();

    imageReader.setInput(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData)), true);

    // read metadata of first image
    IIOMetadata metadata = imageReader.getImageMetadata(0);

    //this cast helps getting the contents
    PNGMetadata pngmeta = (PNGMetadata) metadata; 
    NodeList childNodes = pngmeta.getStandardTextNode().getChildNodes();

    for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = childNodes.item(i);
        String keyword = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("keyword").getNodeValue();
        String value = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").getNodeValue();
        if(key.equals(keyword)){
            return value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Very helpful!! It only required minor modifications to work with 'iTXt' data instead of 'tEXt' data too. Many thanks!

Comment: @Rogel Garicia Which library are you using in this ?

Comment: @AnkeshkumarJaisansaria sorry about being so late... I am just using regular java classes.. no libraries (oracle distribution)

Comment: There is a constant `IIOMetadataFormatImpl.standardMetadataFormatName` that can be used in place of the literal "javax_imageio_png_1.0".

Answer (score 1):

Java provides the [`metadata`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/package-summary.html) package and the [`ImageWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html) class along with the [`ImageIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) package.

You create your [`IIOMetadata`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadata.html) object, then `getImageWriters` for your [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) or [`IIOImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/imageio/IIOImage.html) and use them to `write` the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

To add to other answer, you can also try the [PNGJ](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj/) library, it has full metadata support.

BTW, I don't understand what you are refering to with the "XML-like" structure of metadata.

Comment: looks very promising, I will give it a try. Thanks !

Comment: "Metadata may contain complex, hierarchical structures. The Java XML Document Object Model (DOM) API is used to represent these structures..." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/imageio/spec/apps.fm5.html

Answer (score 0):

Using the method from posted by the OP gets most of the way there; the only issue is that `PNGMetadata` is proprietary and so causes compiler warnings.

There is a method of doing it without using the proprietary API, by searching the metadata tree for `tEXtEntry` nodes:

```
private List<Node> findNodesWithName(String name, Node root) {
    List<Node> found = new ArrayList<>();
    Node n = root.getFirstChild();
    while (n != null) {
        if (n.getNodeName().equals(name)) {
            found.add(n);
        }
        found.addAll(findNodesWithName(name, n));
        n = n.getNextSibling();
    }
}

// ...
// To use it:
IIOMetadata metadata = ...;
List<Node> tEXtNodes = findNodesWithName(
        "tEXtEntry",
        metadata.getAsTree(metadata.getNativeMetadataFormatName()));

for (Node n : tEXtNodes) {
    String keyword = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("keyword");
    String value = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("value");
    System.out.println("keyword: " + keyword + "; value: " + value);
}
```