# How to extract metadata from image

Tags: java, android, eclipse, metadata

Friends Help Me ....

How to extract metadata from image that contains url as a meta data 
If i click the image it must open the corresponding link by accessing the metadata of the image

Thanks in Advance .....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637011/how-to-extract-metadata-from-image - i think this related topic will help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495518/writing-image-metadata-in-java-preferably-png - ou many sory. This is correct link. It can be done only with external lybraries like http://code.google.com/p/pngj/