# How to take screenshot with url in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium

How can I add the url to the screenshot with c# in Selenium. Is there a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the solution. it works and get the url displayed.

---

Use the steps below to add a URL to a screenshot in Selenium with C#

**1- Create a extension:**

```cs
     public static Screenshot AddURLToImage(this Screenshot screenshot, string url)
        {
            string base64 = String.Empty;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(screenshot.AsByteArray, 0, screenshot.AsByteArray.Length))
            {
                Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
                Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);
                using (var font = new Font("Arial", 11))
                {
                    graphics.DrawString(url, font, Brushes.White, 10, 10);
                    var imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
                    byte[] buffer = (byte[])imageConverter.ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));
                    base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
                }
            }
    
            var screenshotWithUrl = new Screenshot(base64);
            return screenshotWithUrl;
        }
```

**2- Get a screenshot with Selenium**

```cs
   Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)Driver).GetScreenshot();
```

**3- Add URL to image and save it**

```cs
    screenshot.AddURLToImage(url).SaveAsFile(path);
```