# Want to add custom metadata to image using Java

Tags: java, metadata

I am using commons.imaging library to add metadata to image by using exifDirectory.add() and exifDirectory.removeField() functions.
But I am not able to add customized tag in image. 
Can someone help me out with this.
Instead of "ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_EXPOSURE" I want my own custom title

```
final JpegImageMetadata metadata =(JpegImageMetadata)Imaging.getMetadata(jpegImageFile);
final JpegImageMetadata jpegMetadata = metadata;
final TiffOutputDirectory exifDirectory = outputSet.getOrCreateExifDirectory();              
exifDirectory.removeField(ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_EXPOSURE);
exifDirectory.add(ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_EXPOSURE, "P100111");
```

Comment: See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495518/writing-image-metadata-in-java-preferably-png) it could help you

Comment: _"I am not able to add customized tag in image"_ -- what actually happens? How can you tell?  How do you know? What makes you think you can change the title associated with a tag?

Comment: I have some information which I need to bind with image metadata with title and the value.Ex: <Car_model>--><Alpha_z1>, <title_name> --><value>. For that reason came up with a solution to append new metatag in image. So is it possible to bind custom metadata tag like this ?